# Subscribe to endpoint_state, and save the pose position coordinates for later use

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the terminal, I'm entering in

```
$ rostopic echo /robot/limb/left/endpoint_state
```

to get the position of the endpoints. The output comes out like this:

```
pose:  
position: x: 0.0881700859423
y: 0.666633918353
z: -0.25671871773  
...
```

Now, in my program, I want to subscribe to this topic and retrieve just the above coordinates: the pose x, y and z. My subscriber looks like this:

```
ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("/robot/limb/left/endpoint_state", 1, leftEndpointCallback)
```

In my callback, I'm trying to get just these specific coordinates as floats or doubles or whatever data type they are, and be able to use them later in my code (i.e. use the x coordinate in an if statement, for example). How would I do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/181923/subscribe-to-endpoint_state,-and-save-the-pose-position-coordinates-for-later-use/) by [grisam](https://answers.ros.org/users/18776/grisam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first thing to do is determine what is the message used in that topic, e.g:

```
$ rostopic info /robot/limb/left/endpoint_state
Type: baxter_core_msgs/EndpointState
```

Therefore, your function `leftEndpointCallback` should look like this:

```
void leftEndpointCallback(const baxter_core_msgs::EndpointStateConstPtr& _msg) 
{
  // The pose is within the _msg object
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("pose: " << _msg->pose);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("pose.position.x: " << _msg->pose.position.x);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("pose.position.y: " << _msg->pose.position.y);
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("pose.position.z: " << _msg->pose.position.z);
}
```

How to use these values somewhere else is scope of C/C++ callbacks. If you really need to process this data outside the callback you may consider implementing a Class. It seems that most people hate global variables (count me as well)

---

Originally posted by [Francisco](https://answers.ros.org/users/17926/francisco/) with karma: 31 on 2014-07-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grisam](https://answers.ros.org/users/18776/grisam/) on 2014-07-23**:
Is there a way I could do this and get only ONE specific point? I keep getting a stream of points but I only want the coordinates at one time instance. Also, what do you mean it's within the scope? If I save _msg->pose.position.x as a variable, how would I access that variable outside the callback?